# NullPointerException with Stanford NLP Spanish POS tagging

Tags: stanford-nlp

All -

Running Stanford CoreNLP 3.4.1, plus the Spanish models. I have a directory of approximately 100 Spanish raw text documents, UTF-8 encoded. For each one, I execute the following commandline:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar:stanford-spanish-corenlp-2014-08-26-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-0.23.jar -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props <propsfile> -file <txtfile>
```

The props file looks like this:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos
tokenize.language = es
pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/spanish/spanish-distsim.tagger
```

For almost every file, I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error annotating :
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$15.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1287)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1347)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1389)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1459)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.ExtractorSpanishStrippedVerb.extract(ExtractorFramesRare.java:1626)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.Extractor.extract(Extractor.java:153)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getExactHistories(TestSentence.java:465)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getHistories(TestSentence.java:440)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getHistories(TestSentence.java:428)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getExactScores(TestSentence.java:377)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getScores(TestSentence.java:372)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.scoresOf(TestSentence.java:713)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:91)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.runTagInference(TestSentence.java:322)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.testTagInference(TestSentence.java:312)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.tagSentence(TestSentence.java:135)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagSentence(MaxentTagger.java:998)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.doOneSentence(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:147)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.annotate(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:110)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:67)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:847)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$15.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1275)

Any ideas? I haven't even begun to track this down. I'm certain the problem is in POS; tokenize and ssplit run just fine.

P.S. Please don't say "Upgrade to 3.5.0"; I don't currently have Java 8 installed and don't want to install it yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem with a fresh download of CoreNLP 3.4.1 and the Spanish models jar from 2014-08-26 (on either Java 7 or Java 8). Can you try redownloading the Spanish models jar / CoreNLP jar?

Comment: Fresh download of both. MacOS 10.9.5, Java 1.7.0_72. Same error.

Comment: A representative input sentence that causes it to fail is:

México captura a uno de los hombres más sanguinarios.

Comment: Aha, I see.. definitely a bug! I will track this down a bit later today. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems like there's a bug in the 3.4.1 Spanish models.

The Spanish 3.5.0 models actually seem to be compatible with Java 7. You can download the models used in 3.5 ([`stanford-spanish-corenlp-2014-10-23-models.jar`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-spanish-corenlp-2014-10-23-models.jar)) and put that on your classpath instead. This fixed the problem for me running Java 7 locally.